# optparse main function, how to use the options inside

Tags: python, function, class, program-entry-point, optparse

I have a script with several functions and is too long to write here, but I am implementing `optparse` in a main function, which is:

```
def main():
    usage = "useage: %prog [options]"
    parser = OptionParser(usage)
    parser.add_option("-f", "--file", type="string", dest="filename", help="Get the name of the cabling file")
    parser.add_option("-i","--imod",dest="modules", help="write the modules in order to get some info",metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_option("-d","--data", type="string", dest="datas",default=True, help="write the options of the Info about a (set of) module(s)")
    parser.add_option("-j","--values", type="string", dest="infor",default=True, help="Modules associated to a(some) value(s)")
    parser.add_option("-k","--common", type="string", dest="common",default=True, help="Values with modules in common")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if (options.filename is None):
        parser.error("No cabling filename was given!")


    #Info about modules    
    list1 = options.modules.split(',')
    list2 = options.datas.split(',')

    for i in list1:
        print "For module with DetId\n: %r " % (i)
    for j in ist2: 
        print  "%r is: %r" % (j,MyHVDict[i][j]) 
    if __name__=="__main__":
        main()
```

The script has some other functions, which depends on the input of the user (like a `filename` and the options defined in the main function) so how can i use the options I defined inside this main function, for example if everything is outside the main function I would just have to write `options.filename` or `options.modules`, anytime I need this, but inside the  function I do not know what to do.

Comment: You can't (easily) access `options` from outside `main`; if a function being called from `main` needs access to `options`, pass either the whole object or the specific options required as explicit arguments.

Comment: Could be a copy-paste error, but that last block `if __name__ == "__main__":` should not be indented.

Comment: so, should i write the other functions inside the main function or implement the optparse without a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your functions are called inside de main function you can pass `options.what_you_need_in_function` as an parameter.

```
def your_funcion(parameter_you_need):
    ...

def main():
    ...
    your_function(options.what_you_need_in_function)
    ...
```

BTW `optparse` module was deprecated, you can change to [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) module.

Comment: but if i put the main() function at the bottom, since there is an input for, for example your_funcion, the latter won't execute,

Comment: Sorry @marycrant,  I dont understand.